# NDesk doesn't throw expected exception

Tags: c#, ndesk.options

NDesk doesn't throw exceptions while parsing `args`. When I do debug without any arguments, the next step after `try` is the `if` and not the `catch` section. Any suggestions?

My code is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NDesk.Options;
namespace test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string emailFrom = "";
            string emailTo = "";
            string emailSubject = "";
            string emailBody = "";
            bool showHelp = false;
            var p = new OptionSet()
            {
                { "f|from", "email to send from", v => emailFrom = v },
                { "t|to", "email to send to", v => emailTo = v },
                { "s|subject", "subject of email", v => emailSubject = v },
                { "b|body", "body of email", v => emailBody= v },
                { "h|help", "show this help and exit", v => showHelp = v != null }
            };
            List<string> extra;
            try
            {
                extra = p.Parse(args);
            }
            catch (OptionException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Try `{0} --help` for more information.", projectName);
                return;
            }
            if (showHelp)
            {
                ShowHelp(p);
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

        private static void ShowHelp(OptionSet p)
        {
            // show help
        }
    }
}
```

I am following the documentation here:
http://ndesk.org/doc/ndesk-options/NDesk.Options/OptionSet.html.

Comment: Do you expect it to throw an exception? If it doesn't require arguments, then what you see is the correct behavior.

Comment: It is example from documentation.
Behavior should be - if command-line doesn't contain any arguments, exception is thrown.

Comment: If you are referencing a tutorial, please link to the tutorial in your post.

Comment: I'm referencing to documentation - not tutorial

Comment: http://www.ndesk.org/doc/ndesk-options/NDesk.Options/OptionSet.html

Comment: @ConnorLow, do you have any suggestions?